# Facebook application development

Tags: php, facebook

Is there any sample facebook application in PHP available somewhere that i can look at and see how things work? I'm trying to developa a application all the resources that i seem to find are with the old php-facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/04168d544f71293fab7622fa81161eef51db808e

get into "examples" and look at the file: example.php

Facebook's own documentation is very good too:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/